# How to use kpr() or dsm() when i am not logged in

Tags: users, debugging

I need to access my login form array using kpr() and dsm() functions but it's not working when I logged out from the site. How to debug and access the login form array as logged out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to grant the *Access developer information* permission to the anonymous user role.

Be sure to revoke it again before releasing the site, it's an easy way to leak sensitive information.

Comment: So, I need to give permission of devel module to the anonymous user.?

Comment: Yes, developer output is hidden from anonymous users by default (for probably obvious reasons)